# Adding Custom UIBarButtonItem not working

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

My goal is to add a button to the right of my navigation item. The thing is, the tintColor on my UINavigationItem is a dark gray color, but I want the button (UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd) to be white, not gray.

After reading around, it appears that I have to make my own custom image that is white in order to accomplish this, which I've done, and I'm setting up with the following code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                             initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomAddButton.png"]                                                                   
                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                        target:self
                                                        action:@selector(addNewItem)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

where CustomAddButton@2x.png is a 40x40 image with an alpha layer and only a white plus.
Instead of the image showing up as white, it's a slightly lighter gray than the tintColor
of the navigationItem that it's contained in. Is there a way to get the UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd to appear white without creating a custom image? If not, what am I
doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` doesn't look as you imagine on `UINavigationBar`, you can use below code:

```
UIImage* addImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, addImage.size.width, addImage.size.height);
UIButton *addButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[addButton setBackgroundImage:addImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[addButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
UIBarButtonItem *addBarButtonItem =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:addButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addBarButtonItem;
```

Cheers ..